# 05 Buick lacrosse

Tags: engine, oil, buick, lacrosse

My car said I was low on oil and I accidently put in about 3/4 of a quart of sae30 instead of 5w30. Will it be ok to fill it the rest the way with the correct oil ? What should I do?

Comment: It's basically OK but are you expecting a lot of arctic cold operation?  If so, I'd fill the rest with 5W20 to balance it out.  Otherwise don't worry about it.

Answer (score 3):

It's of little significance especially in the short-term.  Besides, you diluted the SAE30 with the existing 5W30.

The difference is that SAE30 is "straight" weight oil.  The 5W in 5W-30 means that it has modifiers added to make it flow better at low temperatures.  This helps the engine to turn over easier and start in cold weather.

If this were my car, I'd go ahead and put the rest of the SAE30 in there to top it off.  Then just change the oil when it's due again.